# How to disable legend in nvd3 or limit it's size

Tags: d3.js, legend, scatter-plot, nvd3.js, bubble-chart

I'm using nvd3 and have a few charts where the legend is much to large. E.g. a scatter/bubble with 15 groups and the group names are long. The legend is so large that it leaves almost no room for the chart itself.

Is there a way to remove the legend or toggle the legend or limit the height/width it is taking up? Any example would be great.

Also, is there a way to have the bubble show a descriptive string? Right now when you stand on top of a bubble it highlights the x/y coordinates. I also want it to show the bubble name.

For example, each of my bubbles represents a country (which has a name), the x is GDP and the y is debt. The group is a classification/not name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.showLegend(false)` will help you. Here is an example -

```
chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart().x(function(d) {
                return d.x
            }).y(function(d) {
                return d.y
            }).showLegend(false);
```

Comment: The documentation is not great, but a look at the source code has helped me a few times. In this case, look at https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/pieChart.js