# How to use custom legends in NVD3 charts

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am using an NVD3 line chart.

[image]

The chart by default renders legends which are clickable.

I want to build a custom legend using `<ul>` and `<li>` elements; clicking these `<li>`s should toggle their respective line series on the chart.

```js
$(function(){
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var dayChart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .options({
                transitionDuration: 300,
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                interpolate: 'monotone'
            });

        dayChart.xAxis
            .axisLabel('Time')
            .tickValues([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
            .tickFormat(function(d){
                return ["", "0-6", "6-12", "12-18", "18-24"][d]
            });

        dayChart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Engagement')
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                if (d == null) {
                    return 'N/A';
                }
                return d3.format(',d')(d);
            })
        ;

        var data = [
                {"values": [
                    { "x": 0 ,"y": 3 }, { "x": 1 ,"y": 5 }, { "x": 2 ,"y": 2 }, { "x": 3 ,"y": 4 }, { "x": 4 ,"y": 2 }],    "key": "Desktop","color":"#4b758d"
                }
                ,
                {"values": [
                    { "x":  0 ,"y": 1 },    { "x": 1 ,"y": 3 }, { "x": 2 ,"y": 4 }, { "x": 3 ,"y": 3 }],    "key": "Mobile","color":"#99c925"                },
                {"values": [
                    { "x": 0  ,"y": 2 },{"x": 1  ,"y": 4 }, { "x": 2 ,"y": 3 }, { "x": 3 ,"y": 5 }],"key": "Tablet","color":"#f23b71"                }
            ];

        d3.select('#line-chart').append('svg')
            .datum(data)
            .call(dayChart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(dayChart.update);

        return dayChart;
    });
});
```

Plunker for full [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VyqIMLDWxTmMqN3NCE61?p=preview).

Comment: Can you please add code over the fiddle so will help you

Answer (score 4):

To disable the legend `chart.showLedgend(false)`. More details on how the [entire code looks here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009959/how-to-disable-legend-in-nvd3-or-limit-its-size).

Assuming you have a global instance of your chart, you need to change the state of the chart.

```
$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(){
    chart.dispatch.changeState('key');
    chart.update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', 
    function(){
        var state = chart.state;
        state.disabled[idOfItemInLegend] = !state.disabled[idOfItemInLegend];
        chart.dispatch.changeState(state);
        chart.update();
    }
);
```